# Changing the channel name

Tags: ibm-mq

How do I change the name of an existing channel. My client has informed me that they are changing the channel but keeping the CONNAME the same. I am not able to use the ALTER function. Should I DELETE and re-DEFINE the channel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IBM MQ does not have a `RENAME` action, so you would need to `DEFINE` a new channel and once you are no longer using the old channel `DELETE` it.

To make it easier you can use the `LIKE` verb to copy most (if not all) of the parameters of the old channel to the new channel, for example:

```
DEFINE CHL(NEW.CHL) CHLTYPE(SDR) LIKE(OLD.CHL)
```

In the above case the `NEW.CHL` will have the same values as `OLD.CHL` for things like `XMITQ`, `CONNAME`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Josh for the answer. Can I also have multiple CONNAME on the same channel separated by commas?

Comment: You can if you are using MQ v7.0 or later. Please click the Check mark to the left of my answer to accept it if this answered your original question.

Comment: Can you provide me the syntax for multiple CONNAME as I am getting syntax errors when I include multiple IP address

Comment: Please open a new question,  include details of mq version, command that you ran,  and the exact output including any error messages.